# How to toggle CSS class on <body> tag using vanillaJS - No JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to apply a CSS class to the `<body>` tag of an HTML document?

I have so far been attempting something as such:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("body").add("cssClass");
```

The hope is to apply a filter over the entire DOM as to darken the page at specific times, but keep all functionality of the DOM itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or, shorter: `document.body.className = 'classname';`

As suggested by Gaby, to avoid replacing of already applied class(es):

```
document.body.classList.add('classname')
```

Comment: Your current code will replace any other class currently applied on the `body`. Better use `document.body.classList.add('classname')`

Answer (score 7):

Nobody talks about there exist a `toggle` property.

```
document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
```

Comment: I wish this worked but it doesn't appear to, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = 'yo';
```

```css
.yo {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('your-class')
```

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a node list, so you'll need to access the first (and only) element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the class list of the body - and also TagName returns a nodelist

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('cssClass')
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost, you need to use `document.getElementsByTagName()` and use like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do this with ES6:

`document.querySelector('body');`

This codepen example shows how to toggle a class:

https://codepen.io/kylecasestack/pen/zpKZOq

Comment: What does ES6 have to do with this ?

Comment: What if they are using a browser that may be incompatible with ES6?

Comment: well `document.querySelector` is not related to ES6. ES6 is the javascript standard and has nothing to do with the DOM Api.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @KyleSullivan thanks for helping